# What is the benefit of `lifting` a method to a `Function`?

Tags: scala

I read that "lift" could be used to lift a method invocation into a function. The example was

```
scala> def times2(i: Int) = i * 2
times2: (i: Int)Int
```

We lift a method into a function by applying the underscore

```
scala> val f = times2 _
f: Int => Int = <function1>

scala> f(4)
res0: Int = 8
```

What is the advantage of this? I could use either of f(4) or times2(4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A method must be *lifted* when you want to pass it as an argument to a higher order function. For example if you have an `f: Int => Int` and a  higher order function

```
def higherOrderFunction(f: Int => Int): Int = f(42)
```

you can pass `f` to it. You can't do it with a method, because a method is not a value. However, the method can be *lifted* to a function value:

```
def higherOrderFunction(f: Int => Int): Int = f(42)
def times2(i: Int) = i * 2
val f = times2 _
println(higherOrderFunction(f)) // prints 84
```

Now, this might seem like not a big deal, because you could write `times2` directly instead of `f` when passing it into `higherOrderFunction`, because scala would desugar it into something that looks very much like `f` anyway.

Here is an example where the *syntax* `(times2 _)` is actually useful:

```
val times4: Int => Int = (times2 _) andThen (times2 _)
println(times4(100))
```

This prints `400`.

The point is that `f` is a first-class citizen value: you can store it in a data structure of some sort, or send it over the network. That's the whole point of functional programming: that you can pass functions and closures to higher order functions.

Answer (score 1):

Scala is an object-oriented language. You can *only* do stuff with objects. You can only store objects in variables. You can only pass objects as arguments. You can only return objects.

Methods are not objects.

Something not being an object is a *really big restriction* in an object-oriented language. You cannot store a method in a variable. You cannot pass a method as an argument. You cannot return a method. You cannot call a method on a method.

So, the possibility of lifting a method (which is not an object) into a function (which *is* an object), is a big deal, since it removes all the restrictions and allows you all the things you can do with any other object.