# Scala function typing issue

Tags: scala

I'm given a list `lis` of type `List[(Char,Int)]` and need to sort it by chars, but I want do do this using `sortWith` function. One way to do this is using:

```
val newlis = lis.sortWith({case ((a,b),(c,d)) => a<c })
```

But when I wrote auxilary function:

```
def aux2(term: ((Char, Int),(Char, Int)) ): Boolean = term match {
  case ((a,b),(c,d)) => a<c
  case _ => false
}
lis.sortWith(aux2)
```

I get type mismatch. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between

```
def f(a: A, b: B): C
```

and

```
def f(ab: (A, B)): C
```

When [lifted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48905121/what-is-the-benefit-of-lifting-a-method-to-a-function/48905315#48905315) and desugared, the first one becomes a `Function2[A, B, C]`, while the second one becomes `Function[(A, B), C]`. While essentially the same (*isomorphic*), these two types must be used with a slightly different syntax.

Here is a slightly more complex example with  `(Char, Int)` instead of `A` and `B`:

```
def g1(abcd: ((Char, Int), (Char, Int))): Boolean = abcd._1._2 < abcd._2._2
val g1Fun: (((Char, Int), (Char, Int))) => Boolean = g1
//         ^^^            ^
//         || \           second component of tuple: (Char, Int)
//         ||  first component of tuple: (Char, Int)
//         | \
//         |  single argument of type ((Char, Int),(Char, Int))
//          \
//           argument list of `g1Fun`, accepts *one* argument


def g2(ab: (Char, Int), cd: (Char, Int)): Boolean = ab._2 < cd._2
val g2Fun: ((Char, Int), (Char, Int)) => Boolean = g2
//         ^^            ^
//         ||            second argument of type (Char, Int)
//         | \
//         |  first argument of type (Char, Int)
//          \
//           argument list of `g2Fun`, needs *two* arguments
```

The function `lt` in `sortWith` behaves like the second function `g2Fun`, whereas the function `aux2` that you have written is more like the `g1Fun`.

---

So, to fix your code, you have to define `aux2` as a *binary* operation:

```
val lis: List[(Char,Int)] = List(('a', 34), ('b', 42))

println(lis.sortWith({case ((a,b),(c,d)) => a < c }))

def aux2(
  firstTerm: (Char, Int), 
  secondTerm: (Char, Int) 
): Boolean = (firstTerm, secondTerm) match {
  case ((a,b), (c,d)) => a < c
  case _ => false
}

println(lis.sortWith(aux2))
```

To make it work with the same arity of `f` as you have written, the `sortWith` would have to accept a slightly different sort of functions.
Consider this:

```
def watchTheArity(f: ((Int, Int)) => Int): Int = {
  f((4, 5))
}
```

See the weird double parens wrapping the `(Int, Int)` part?

This means: "I expect an `f` that takes a single tuple as argument".

Therefore, this works:

```
def f(ab: (Int, Int)): Int = ab._1 + ab._2

println(watchTheArity(f))
```

However, if it were defined as

```
def watchTheArity2(f: (Int, Int) => Int): Int = {
  f(4, 5)
}
```

then you would need an `f` that takes *two* arguments.

---

**Edit notice** Added Ascii-art explanation of parentheses.

Comment: One more thing 'It: ((Char, Int),(Char,Int)) => Boolean', was the requested type of the function for SortWith. How do I decide wether it is one tuple (of 2 tuples) or two tuples (2 elements each)?

Comment: @GraphLearner Added a detailed explanation of each paren

Comment: @GraphLearner The `lt` is just like `g2Fun`ction.

Comment: @GraphLearner Come on, it's not nearly as horrible as higher-order function-pointer-consumer-callbacks in C ;)