# Map needs not inferred codomain in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

The following Scala code:

```
val l = List((1,2),(2,3),(3,4))
def fun1(t1: Int,t2: Int) = (t1+1,t2)
l map fun1
```

Gives the error:

```
Error:(3, 8) type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => (Int, Int)
 required: ((Int, Int)) => ?
l map fun1;}
      ^
```

I wonder why is it necessary for map to have a function whose codomain has no inferred type...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not about the codomain, it's the wrong function arity.The method `map` expects a function with a single argument, even if this argument is a tuple:

```
((Int, Int)) => (Int, Int) // Function[(Int, Int), (Int, Int)]
```

but you are passing it a function that takes two arguments (two ints):

```
(Int, Int) => (Int, Int)   // Function2[Int, Int, (Int, Int)]
```

Do either this:

```
def fun1(t: (Int, Int)) = (t._1+1, t._2)
l map fun1
```

or this:

```
def fun1(t1: Int,t2: Int) = (t1+1,t2)
l map { case (x, y) => fun1(x, y) }
```

Here is [a similar example with a more detailed explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48911547/scala-function-typing-issue/48911802#48911802) for a similar issue.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `case` to destruct the tuple.

```
val l = List((1,2),(2,3),(3,4))
def fun1(t1: Int,t2: Int) = (t1+1,t2)
l map { case (a, b) => fun1(a, b) }
```

But, if you declare your function like below to make it work

```
def fun1(t: (Int, Int)) = (t._1 + 1,t._2)

l map fun1
```